# How can I convert following code to Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have written a following code in imperative style that is working fine . but i want to convert it to java 8 , I have tried it but could not able to get in most elegant way .

```
List<Wrapper> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Wrapper> pastList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Wrapper> list = fooRepository.findAll();
for(Wrapper data : list){
  if(data.getSchedule().toInstant().isAfter(new Date().toInstant())
       futureList.add(data);
   else
       pastList.add(data);     
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing to do if you want to use `Stream`s is using [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) like that:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Wrapper>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(data -> data.getSchedule().toInstant().isAfter(Instant.now())));
List<Wrapper> pastList = map.get(false);
List<Wrapper> futureList = map.get(true);
```

Comment: thanks . where from i can learn this type of techniques in java 8 ?

Comment: Just Google "java stream tutorial" - the very first result ([Java 8 Stream Tutorial](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/)) looks quite promising. Later on, consult the JavaDocs: [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description), [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) classes.